# CGLib2 not available even though dependencies are included in Maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jboss, maven-3

I am getting this Error when trying to deploy my project to JBoss7:

```
Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
```

I have  added to the pom.xml which is supposed to load the necessary library among others, which looks something like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This seems to load other libraries that I have tried before, but it doesn't seem to work for this particular one.

Here is the full Error:

```
12:13:34,037 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-8) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduleController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager ua.kpi.schedule.controll.ScheduleController.dataProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.dao.TeacherDAO ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager.teacherDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager ua.kpi.schedule.controll.ScheduleController.dataProcessor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.dao.TeacherDAO ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager.teacherDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.dao.TeacherDAO ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager.teacherDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private ua.kpi.schedule.dao.TeacherDAO ua.kpi.schedule.managers.DataManager.teacherDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAopProxyFactory.createAopProxy(DefaultAopProxyFactory.java:67) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyCreatorSupport.createAopProxy(ProxyCreatorSupport.java:104) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322) [spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 more
```

Why do I get this  exception even though I have the necessary dependancies?

Comment: Did you in the end find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Maven then you  must need to add cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar manually to  class path so that we can by pass the exception. In my case its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown because the following check in DefaultAopProxyFactory returns false:

```
ClassUtils.isPresent("net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer", DefaultAopProxyFactory.class.getClassLoader())
```

It seems the classloader that loaded class DefaultAopProxyFactory cannot see the class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhance inside the WAR.

Can you try these things and post back the results:

- check if the cglib jar is inside the WAR
- If you are running Java 7 have a look at [jHades](http://jhades.org), it's a tool meant for these kind of problems (diagnose classpath problems also in server startups)
- Or create a servlet listener, put it in the beginning of your web.wml and query the classpath for the involved classes:

```
System.out.println("All versions of net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhance viewable from the servlet classloader: ");
for (Enumeration e = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.class"); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    System.out.println("- " + e.nextElement());
}

System.out.println("All versions of net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhance viewable from the classloader of DefaultAopProxyFactory: ");
for (Enumeration e = DefaultAopProxyFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResources("net/sf/cglib/proxy/Enhancer.class"); e.hasMoreElements();) {
   System.out.println("- " + e.nextElement());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, my Intellij project named springProject and my artifactId named chapter1, configured Deployment:springProject:war exploded. 
It caused the same problem even though I have cglib in my dependency. 
Finally I changed the artifactId to the same name springProject, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

cglib cannot apply on final classes. The class you are going to extend is marked as Final and we cannot extends the final classes.